# remove alternating colors in ObjectListView

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview-python

I need help removing the alternating colors from my ObjectListView.

```
    self.problist = ObjectListView(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
    self.problist.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Problem", "left", 400, valueGetter="short_des"),
            ColumnDefn("First Treated", "left", 100, valueGetter="prob_date"),
            ColumnDefn("ICD-10 Code", "left", 100, valueGetter="icd10")
            ])
    self.problist.SetObjects(problems)
    self.problist.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_DOUBLECLICK
    self.problist.Bind(EVT_CELL_EDIT_STARTING, self.HandleCellEditStarting)
    self.problist.Bind(EVT_CELL_EDIT_FINISHED, self.HandleCellEditFinished)
    self.problist.rowFormatter = self.rowFormatter
    self.problist.useAlternateBackColors = False
```

I've also tried `self.problist.useAlternateBackColors(False)`.  This is set automatically to True.  After searching through the documentation I haven't found any indications about how one sets this ObjectListView property.

Thanks

Comment: Setting that property to false is working as expected in C#. Are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this before loading the objects.

```
    self.problist = ObjectListView(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.problist.SetColumns([
                ColumnDefn("Problem", "left", 400, valueGetter="short_des"),
                ColumnDefn("First Treated", "left", 100, valueGetter="prob_date"),
                ColumnDefn("ICD-10 Code", "left", 100, valueGetter="icd10")
                ])
        self.problist.useAlternateBackColors = False
        self.problist.SetObjects(problems)
        self.problist.cellEditMode = ObjectListView.CELLEDIT_DOUBLECLICK
        self.problist.Bind(EVT_CELL_EDIT_STARTING,   self.HandleCellEditStarting)
        self.problist.Bind(EVT_CELL_EDIT_FINISHED, self.HandleCellEditFinished)
        self.problist.rowFormatter = self.rowFormatter
```

Comment: Solved.  Thanks very much.

Comment: How do I mark it as answered?  The help section is silent on this issue.